# How can I rearrange taxonomy weights for terms with two-deep hierarchies?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy vocabulary on my site of user ages.

It looks like this:

[image: agegroup]

However, I want to change the weight so that 20s is -19, Late Teens is -18, Early 20s is -17, etc.  In other words, I want to change the weight so that when I sort by weight in Views, the terms appear in exactly the same order as shown on the screen above.

However, when I manually adjust the weights to -19, -18, -17, etc., upon saving the list of terms the weights are reverted to those listed above.

I tried individually dragging and dropping each term to change the order, but again when I saved the list, the weights had returned to this pattern:

- Parent A 0
- A Child A 0
- A Child B 1
- A Child C 2
- A Child D 3
- Parent B 1
- B Child A 0
- B Child B 1
- B Child C 2
- Parent C 2
- Parent D 3

etc.

However, when sorting by weight in Views, this then gives a list like:

- Parent A
- A Child A
- B Child A
- C Child A
- A Child B
- Parent B
- B Child B
- C Child B
- A Child C
- B Child C
- Parent C
- C Child C

which looks terrible and makes no sense.

How can I manually control the weights and override whatever processing Drupal is applying to them?

Comment: Have you set a relationship of "Taxonomy term: Parent term" added a field with that relationship and set grouping by this field? I have something similar working here, and even if i rearrange the taxonomy, the changes are represented by the view... maybe some other glitch?

Answer (score 4):

For such small taxonomies (large and frequently changing ones will be a pain) you may create special custom field for flat sorting order, since weights are meant to be used on a certain hierarchy level:

[image: custom field]

Then you just add some sort criteria to your views:

[image: sort criteria]

Considering this terms structure:

[image: taxonomy terms structure]

you will get this output:

[image: view result]

**Good thing:** this requires no code hacking at all, yet supports all Views features like caching.

**Bad thing:** you will go mad with setting this field values for large vocabularies.

Answer (score 2):

This should work to get the desired output in views and enable you to rearrange your terms at will:

1. Configure Relationship: Taxonomy term: Parent term, make this relationship required.
2. Add another (second) field: Taxonomy term: Name, set the relationship to the parent and exclude this from display.
3. Configure sort criterion: Taxonomy term: Weight (asc) and set the relationship to parent
4. Page: Style options, set Grouping field nr.1 to (Parent) Taxonomy term: Name

Answer (score 1):

Try this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_term_hierarchy_weight_field

It will add a normalized weight on every taxonomy term.

Volker solution will exclude parent's terms requiring parent term relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Taxonomy Manger module, I think I face an issue in the past similar to your and I sort it with the Taxonomy manger. Give it a shot. http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager

Comment: How exactly does one go about modifying the weights using Taxonomy Manager?  I have it installed but it's not immediately apparent to me how this would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to re-order the view's result, by using a hook_views_pre_render, according to your taxonomy_tree

```
function custommodule_views_pre_render( &$view ){
  switch ( $view->name ){
    case "myviewname":

      $vid = 1;
      $tree =  taxonomy_get_tree( $vid );

      $result_to_reorder = array();
      //original result
      foreach( $view->result as $result ){
        $tid = $result->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_term['und'][0]['tid'];
        $result_to_reorder[ $tid ][] = $result;
      }

      $result_reordered = array();
      foreach( $tree as $term ){
        $result_for_tid = isset( $result_to_reorder[ $term->tid ] ) ? $result_to_reorder[ $term->tid ] : NULL;

        if( !$result_for_tid ) continue;

        if( count( $result_for_tid ) >= 0 ){
          foreach( $result_for_tid as $value ){
            $result_reordered[] = $value;
          }
        }
      }  
      //set the new result order to the view result
      $view->result = $result_reordered;

      break;
  }
}
```

i hope this could help you

Answer (score 0):

Simply for sorting the taxonomy according to their weights can be done with the help of view ..
In the view we can add **sort Criteria** according to the taxonomy terms either in ascending or in descending order....

Cheers...

Comment: I'm afraid you misread the question. I don't want to sort by weight, I want to change the weight.